# Create two child menus for every parent menu in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've searched for this but no luck. I want to create two child menus for every parent menu in Google Chrome extension. But the code I have yet only creates child menus when the context is "page".
Here's the code I'm currently trying:

```
var contexts = ["page","link","image"];
        for (var i = 0; i < contexts.length; i++) {
      var context = contexts[i];
      var title = "";

      title = "Do something with this "+context;
      var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context]});
      var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "someThing1", "parentId": id, "onclick": onClickFunc});
      var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "someThing2", "parentId": id, "onclick": onClickFunc});
}
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is answered over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18198476/1678601

In short, the create method has an *optional* param called 'contexts' which defaults to 'page' only.

Here's the doc: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create

So, to demonstrate how to apply the solution to your code (this is only a partial from above):

```
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "someThing1", "parentId": id, "onclick": onClickFunc, "contexts": ["page","link","image"]});
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "someThing2", "parentId": id, "onclick": onClickFunc, "contexts": ["page","link","image"]});
```