# Submenu for Web extensions

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, firefox-addon-webextensions

To have a [**context menu in a web extension**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus) we can use

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "clickme",
  title: "Click me!",
  contexts: ["all"]
});
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to have a submenu, is there one?

Comment: parentId: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create#Parameters

Comment: @DanielHerr: Make it an answer so that I can accept it. Was too blind, admittedly.

Comment: Check out the Q/A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818714/adding-children-to-context-menu-links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect the sub-menu with the menu use parameter

> parentId

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create#Parameters

In the example you can see the sub-menus connecting with the `parentId: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS` to the parent menu with the `id: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS`.

The main menu doesn't have a parentId

```
const MENU_ENTRY = {
    DIALOG_OPTIONS: 'DIALOG_OPTIONS',
    DIALOG_OPTIONS_DEFAULT: 'DO_DEFAULT',
    DIALOG_OPTIONS_DETACH: 'DO_DETACH',
}

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS,
    title: browser.i18n.getMessage("contextMenuItemDialogOptions"),
    contexts: ["all"]
}, onCreated);

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS_DETACH,
    parentId: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS,
    type: "radio",
    title: browser.i18n.getMessage("contextMenuItemDialogOptionsDetach"),
    contexts: ["all"],
    checked: true
}, onCreated);

browser.contextMenus.create({
    id: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS_DEFAULT,
    parentId: MENU_ENTRY.DIALOG_OPTIONS,
    type: "radio",
    title: browser.i18n.getMessage("contextMenuItemDialogOptionsDefault"),
    contexts: ["all"],
    checked: false
}, onCreated);

function onCreated(n) {
    if (browser.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(`Error: ${browser.runtime.lastError}`);
    } else {
        console.log("Menu Item created successfully");
    }
}
```